# Alternative To Loops

Tags: matlab, network-programming

This is my code and I want to improve it.

And it is correct, but I want to decrease the time which this code take!

How can I do that ?!

**My code:**

```
D  = [ 0 9 1 ; 0 9 8 ];
f   =D(:, 3);
s  = D(:, 1);
a   = D(:, 2);
t   = 0 : 0.01 : 10;
x    = t.';
i   = 0 : 0.01 : 10;
y    = i.';
E= 1.0000e+025;

for x=0 : 1: 10
    for y =0 :1 :10
        h   = sqrt( (x - s).^2 +(y-a).^2 );
        Ex1 = (q.*(x-Xn)) ./ r.^3  ;
        r  = sum(Ex1);
        Ey1 = (q.*(y-Yn)) ./ r.^3  ;
        r2 = sum(Ey1);
        Et  = sqrt( r^2 + r2^2 );    

        end 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can almost always get rid of `for` loops in Matlab and work directly with arrays of numbers "all at once" (meaning that the loops still happen, but they're implemented in the underlying binary in a highly optimized way).  This process is referred to as "vectorization" and there is a [tutorial on it on the MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) as well as at the end of a hundred Google search results.  The two main tools for you are going to be `meshgrid` (or `ndgrid`, whichever you prefer) and `bsxfun`.  In your particular case I would start with

```
[ x, y] = ndgrid( 0:0.01:10, 0:0.01:10 );
```

Take a look now at the resulting shape, size and values of `x` and `y`.  They allow you to perform operations on `x` and `y` "in one step"—simplest example:  `x+y` now gives you the sums of all possible pairs of `x` and `y` values.

But in your code, you want to add *vectors* (like `-Xn`) to your `x` and `y` values.   Since `x` and `y` are now matrices, they already occupy space in the first two dimensions, so that's a problem.  We could solve this a number of ways—for example, project your vector `Xn` into the third dimension with `Xn = permute(Xn(:), [3 2 1])`. Or it might be cleaner if we shift `x` and `y` into higher dimensions (2 and 3) instead.  So let's revise it to:

```
[ ~, x, y] = ndgrid( 1, 0:0.01:10, 0:0.01:10 );
```

Now subtraction of the column-vector `Xn` can be done without changing its shape.  It's done like this:

```
bsxfun( @minus, x, Xn )    % instead of x-Xn
```

`bsxfun` is necessary because `x` and `Xn` are not exactly the same shape: `Xn` needs to be "tiled" or "broadcast" into dimensions 2 and 3.

So then you continue revising your code in that vein, watching out for your dimensions (for example, whenever you take `sum`, you should always tell it explicitly *which dimension* to summate over).  Finally you'll end up with `Et` the same size and shape as your original `x` and `y`, and you'll want to perform a minimum operation across the dimensions 2 and 3 in which `x` and `y` values varied:

```
[ minValuesDim2,  minLocationsDim2 ] = min( Et, [], 2 );
[ Emin minLocationDim3 ] = min( minValuesDim2, [], 3 );
minLocationDim2 = minLocationsDim2( minLocationDim3 );

% now look up the actual x and y values that correspond to those locations:
Xmin = x( 1, minLocationDim2, 1 );
Ymin = y( 1, 1, minLocationDim3 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your effort .

Comment: It is an useful answer! +1.

Comment: this step :    [ ~, x, y] = ndgrid( 1, 0:0.01:10, 0:0.01:10 ); 

do not work in my matlab and I do not know why !


is there any other step instead of it ?!

Comment: Maybe your version of matlab doesn't support tilde ( `~` ) as a way if denoting discarded output. If so, write `ans` there instead

Comment: do you mean I can project Xn and Yn into the third dimension with Xn = permute(Xn(:), [3 2 1]) , Yn =permute(Yn(:),[3 2 1 ] ) , instead of this method ?!

Comment: Sure. Try it for yourself (but don't try and solve the whole problem at once—try and verify each step as you go along). `shiftdim` is another way to do the necessary transformation of `Xn`.

Answer (score 0):

In your algorithm `for` loops take most of time. If the loops could be avoided, you would gain terrific time performance. As **@jez** mentioned, in your case, you can use combination of [`meshgrid()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [`bsxfun()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) functions instead of using `for` loops which can be an alternative to your `gradient()` thought.

Try this:

```
tic

Q      = [ 0,5,7 ; 2.5,0,7; 2.5,10,7 ; 7.5,0,7 ; 7.5,10,7 ; 10,5,7 ]; 
% // Q      = [ 9,5,4 ; 10,1,7 ; 4,6,10 ];  % // You can write any Q matrix you want
Xn     = Q(:, 1);
Yn     = Q(:, 2);
q      = Q(:, 3);
len    = length(Xn);
x      = meshgrid([0 : .01 : 10]'); % // Enter your x vector to meshgrid() as an argument
% // [~, y] = meshgrid([0 : .01 : 10]'); % // Enter your y vector to meshgrid() as an argument
[U, y] = meshgrid([0 : .01 : 10]'); % // U refer to unnecessary variable. You should do it like that because tilde sign isn' t defined in your MATLAB version..
X      = meshgrid( x, zeros(len, 1) );      
Y      = meshgrid( y, zeros(1, len) );
xDif   = bsxfun(@minus, X, Xn);
yDif   = bsxfun(@minus, Y, Yn);
r      = sqrt( xDif.^2 + yDif.^2 );
Ex1    = ( bsxfun(@times, xDif, q) ) ./ ( r.^3 );
Ey1    = ( bsxfun(@times, yDif, q) ) ./ ( r.^3 );
Ex     = sum(Ex1, 1);
Ey     = sum(Ey1, 1);
Et     = sqrt(Ex.^2 + Ey.^2);
Emin   = min(Et);
indMin = find(Et==Emin);
Xmin   = X(1, indMin);
Ymin   = Y(1, indMin);

toc
```

Using this code my time gain is **`17.582351 - 1.740135 = 15.8422 seconds`** wrt my PC.

---

**Execution Samples of Code:**

**# For `Q = [ 0,5,7 ; 2.5,0,7; 2.5,10,7 ; 7.5,0,7 ; 7.5,10,7 ; 10,5,7 ];`:**
[image]

**# For `Q = [ 9,5,4 ; 10,1,7 ; 4,6,10 ];`:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your effort .

Comment: there is an error .

when I tried to input :

 Q=[ 9,5,4 ; 10,1,7 ; 4,6,10 ];

answer was false .

Comment: @ÐiffëřëņtĞîRl, Yeah you are right, I had just missed a point. I have corrected it and edited my answer, now you can enter any Q matrix you want. Good luck..

Comment: still doesn't work

    ??? [~, y] = meshgrid([0 : .01 : 10]'); % // Enter your y vector to meshgrid() as an argument
      |
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: @ÐiffëřëņtĞîRl, I have just copied the code from my answer and pasted it to command window in MATLAB and it worked well. I have taken screen shot and shared it in my answer.

Comment: Interesting... I don't know either!.